# Wordpress wp-cron not working

Tags: wp-cron

Cron is not working as expected. If i schedule post or Event Manager event it never get published if the site is accessed after published time.

If i go to http://somedomain.tld/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron it's empty instead debugging is set on. Should it be empty or should it display some errors if there is any?

Error log is empty.

WP Crontrol plugin displays cron jobs.

[image]

Any hint what to check next?

Comment: is the "wp-cron.php" publicly accessible ? e.g. if there is a password protection with .htaccess file, WordPress cannot acces is own wp-cron.php

Comment: No there is no password protection.

Comment: Oh, i never set correct timezone in Wordpress.

Comment: Shall the wordpress timezone and server timezone be same?

Answer (score 3):

Check the Wordpress timezone setting before ripping your hair or making any big changes to files.